# Jquery HTTP status from $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Here is the AJAX (cross-domain) call I am making from my HTML page.

```
    var deffered = $.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,        
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    origin:window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
    timeout:5000,
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }
```

Now the problem i am facing is whenever the AJAX call is failing, I am not getting the expected HTTP status code.  Its always coming as zero (0).  I cannot make any change in my server side code.  So at this situation is there any solution to get the HTTP status code like 404, 500 or any other HTTP code in case of failure.  In case of success i am able to get HTTP code as 200.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The CORS headers are _response_ headers, they have to be set by the server. Letting the client set them would completely defeat the purpose.

Comment: Look into setting the `complete: function(){ //do something here }` callback so that something ALWAYS happens at the end of the AJAX processing

Comment: I am actually handling the response and error from deffered.done(function(data,status, xhr){}) and deffered.fail(function(data,status, xhr){}).  In the fail, i am getting the status always as zero(0).  But I am expecting Http errors like 404 or 405, in case of failures.